# Working with the NSSortDescriptor

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data, nssortdescriptor

I am using with a sortDescriptor to sort my NSFetchRequest result. I am doing this.

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Team"];
    request.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"position" ascending:YES]];
```

Position can be 4 values:

1. Atacker
2. Goalkeeper
3. Winger
4. Defender

At the moment it groups all the positions seperatyl. So first all the attackers, then all the goalkeepers, then all the defenders and finally all of the wingers. What I want to achieve now is to change the order of rank. The order of rank should be.

1. First all the goalkeepers
2. Second all the defenders
3. Third all the wingers
4. And lastly all the wingers

Anybody got an idea how I can do that ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A messy way of doing it would be to add an extra integer column representing each player type and sorting it by that instead.

EDIT: This isn't necessarily a 'messy' method because it does the job however the only reason I had suggested it was messy was because you have to add in extra stuff so that you know the kind of player. Despite this, it is a reasonable method.

Comment: I think there is a better way to do that. But If not I will definitely take a look at this.

Comment: This doesn't seem particularly elegant but it work. You could always add in an array to pull the names from if you've got the integer.

Comment: I do not consider this a messy solution (+1). A fetch request from a SQLite store can only sort on keys which are stored as attributes in the data base. It is therefore OK to add an auxiliary column for a custom sort order. - The only alternative is to sort the results after fetching them.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a relationship which store all objects you can prepare helper methods which will sort items form NSSet using NSSortDescriptors with prepared block. Or you can fetch all objects and then just sort them.

Comment: I only have a entity which stores all players. No relationship

Comment: Then you can make a fetch to get all objects and sort the array returned by executeFetchRequest.